# Geometry Nodes: Start point of the curve does not affected when using the Trim Curve node

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, instances

I'm using Proximity to change Z-position of the instances. Proximity is controlled by the Trim Curve node. The problem is that the start point of the curve is not affected. Is there a way to fix this with Trim Curve, or is there a more elegant solution?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you can only cover a part of the curve with your value for "Factor", because this runs from $0$ to $1$.

You can therefore solve this differently and with fewer nodes:

[image]

1. First use `Capture Attribute` at the very beginning of your node tree and capture the *Curve Factor* there.
2. After that, since this value will be transferred to all instances, subtract it from your input, which you multiply by $1.1$ before (so it will always be somewhere between $0$ and $1.1$).
3. Then map these values to the range you want, but limit the *From Max* value to $0.1$.

Since you previously multiplied the input by $1.1$, and now set $0.1$ as *From Max*, you will get a smooth transition in the range $0.1$. If you want to increase this transition, first multiply by $1.5$ and set *From Max* to $0.5$.

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.4+)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution!